# Kotlin - using a generic mapping by passing Class

Tags: kotlin

I'm using some library (KotliQuery) to access my database.

It works as follows :

```
val toUser: (Row) -> User = { row ->
        User(
            id = row.int("id"),
            name = row.string("name"),
            lastName = row.stringOrNull("last_name")
        )
    }

suspend fun <T : Any> query(statement: String, vararg params: Any?, transform: (Row) -> T): List<T>? = dbQuery {
        var result: List<T>? = null
        using(db) { session ->
            result = session.run(queryOf(statement, "John")
                .map(toUser)
                .asList
            )
        }
        result
    }
```

The map function inside the library is :

```
fun <A> map(extractor: (Row) -> A?): ResultQueryActionBuilder<A> {
        return ResultQueryActionBuilder(this, extractor)
    }
```

What I want to achieve is a generic usage of mapping from DB to Model.
Example of how I want to use it:

```
val result = db.query<User>(someStatement, "John")
```

Here I simply want to pass the `User` inside the `< >`.
The User model will have the `extractor: (Row) -> A?` override which the code above could use.

For example - User.kt :

```
fun <A: Any> extractor(): (Row) -> A? = { row ->
            User(
                id = row.int("id"),
                name = row.string("name"),
                lastName = row.stringOrNull("last_name")
            )
        }
```

and then I simply could use `.map(T.extractor())` inside the query function.

However, I cannot seem to get it to work.

**EDIT**:

following Sweeper's comment, I tried refactoring the `query` method as follows :

```
suspend inline fun <reified T: Any> query(st: String, params: String): List<T> = dbQuery {
        var result: List<T> = listOf()
        using(db) { session ->
            result = session.run(queryOf(st, "John")
                .map( map[T::class] as ((Row) -> T) )
                .asList)
        }
        result
    }
```

However, the `map[...]` makes the compiler shout at me, I probably don't understand fully how to implement it in the model side.

**EDIT 2 :**

Inside User.kt I added :

```
companion object {
        val toUser: (Row) -> User = { row ->
            User(
                id = row.int("id"),
                name = row.string("name"),
                lastName = row.stringOrNull("last_name")
            )
        }
    }
```

Inside the DB layer :

```
  val map = mapOf(User::class to User.toUser)

    suspend inline fun <reified T: Any> query(st: String, params: String): List<T> = dbQuery {
        var result: List<T> = listOf()
        using(db) { session ->
            result = session.run(queryOf(st, "John")
                .map( map[T::class] as ((Row) -> T) )
                .asList)
        }
        result
    }
```

However, `map[T::class]`shouts now that "Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter K should be mentioned in input types. Try to specify it explicitly"

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand, how are you suggesting to implement it with Map<KClass.. ?

Comment: I edited my post (added the edit in the end of the post), hopefully the `query` method is now what you meant, but I can't understand how to complete this solution on the model part.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, and `map` is a map that you would fill in with classes and their corresponding extractor functions. For example, `val map = mapOf(User::class to toUser)`. You can probably give this map a better name :)

Comment: naming is a nice problem to have in my case here :)
I edited it again (in the post too), and now
`map[T::class]`shouts that "Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter K should be mentioned in input types. Try to specify it explicitly".

Also, is there a way to make the code insode User not inside Companion?
because I want the class to override an interface inside the class

Comment: Alright it seems to be working now, thanks!! although the compiler warns me about the `as ((Row) -> T)` cast, saying it's unchecked cast between T and Any. Should I just ignore it?

Also, regarding the companion object inside User, can I somehow get rid of it?
It would be perfect if "toUser" could be more generic like "toDbObject" and would be part of some interface that my models would have to implement.

Using the toUser inside the companion object kind of spoils this direction

Comment: An interface can only require instance methods, and `toUser` by its very nature is not an instance method, so it would not have been possible to do this with interfaces in the first place. You can get rid of the unchecked cast warning if you do a `SuppressWarning`. It's nothing to worry about, as long as you don't put weird things in the map.